# log4j: Change format of loggers configured in another library

Tags: logging, clojure, log4j

Using clojure, I've been able to successfully setup log4j very simply by using this log4j.properties file, and including log4j in my classpath.

```
# BEGIN log4j.properties

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMdd HHmmss SSS} %5p %c [%t] %m\n

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT
```

Then after :use'ing clojure.contrib.logging, I'm able to print a statement with the desired formatting as expected like so:

```
(info "About to print this")
(debug "This is debug-level")
```

My question is how to achieve a consistent formatting for logging statements made from loggers configured in other libraries. I thought I could find existing loggers using org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() and change the PatternLayouts there, but I'm not able to iterate over that enumeration in clojure, as I get the following error:

```
Dont know how to create ISeq from: java.util.Vector$1
```

I assume this is possible somehow, and probably very simply. How?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumeration-seq` instead of `seq`:

```
(enumeration-seq (org.apache.log4j.LogManager/getCurrentLoggers))
```

For the curious, `org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getCurrentLoggers()` returns a `java.util.Enumeration`; `seq` doesn't know how to operate on that, but `enumeration-seq` does.

A simpler case not involving logging:

```
(seq (.elements (java.util.Vector. [1 2 3]))
; => throws an exception

(enumeration-seq (.elements (java.util.Vector. [1 2 3])))
; => returns (1 2 3)
```